# Bidimensional array with one dimension at [1]

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a maintenance project, and I found this array declaration in a C source file:

```
char vectorFields [1][FIELD_SIZE];
char vectorValues [1][VALUE_SIZE];
```

initialized with:

```
strcpy(vectorFields [0], field); // where char field[128]
strcpy(vectorValues [0], vals);  // where char vals[128]
```

does this bidimensional declaration with one size of [1] make sense (optimization, readability, ...) or it is just a legacy code that I can safely update to monodimensional array and adjust the initialization code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of a couple of possible reasons as to how this came about:

1. The row dimension was originally some value > 1 and later was changed to 1. It was easier to leave the declarations like this rather than switch to a simpler declaration and then change every point in the code where these variables are referenced.
2. There is an API somewhere (perhaps external and/or problematic to change) which accepts 2D arrays where the major dimension is dynamic, e.g.

   `void foo(char bar[][FIELD_SIZE], int num_bars);`

However if you have access to all the places where these variables are referenced and there are no obvious constraints such as (2) above then I don't see any reason not to rationalise this usage.

Comment: Paul you were right: in another place where copy&paste coding method was applied (for my pity this bad practice is used a lot in this project) I found perhaps the copied source where the row is indeed > 1.

Comment: @Zac: sadly this is all too common with any code base which has any history to it - even if most of the people who have worked on the code are competent there's always "that guy" who polluted the code during his time at the company (before he got promoted to a management position ;-)).